# How to set HTTP Header for OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, curl, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Am trying to use Spring Secruity's OAuth API to obtain an access token from an externally published API within a Spring MVC 4 based Web Services (not Spring Boot).

This curl command works (and its contents are all that I need to obtain an access token):

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=bcfrtew123&client_secret=Y67493012'
```

Spring Security OAuth API:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My code to obtain access token:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccessToken", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(@RequestParam(value="client_id", required=true) String clientId, @RequestParam(value="client_secret", required=true) String clientSecret) throws Exception {
    String tokenUri = "https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token";

    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
    resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

    oauth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

    OAuth2AccessToken token = oauth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();
    return token;
}
```

When I invoke the getAccessToken call from my local tomcat instance:

```
access_denied 
error_description=Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. 
The provider manager is not configured to support it.
```

Am suspecting the reason is that my Http Header's Content-Type is not set for

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

How do I do set that for:

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
```

If you notice, I am trying to set in inside the @RequestMapping and don't think that its working:

```
@RequestMapping(consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Answer (score 3):

The http headers for accessing the token in Oauth2Restemplate in case of Client credentials are set in below method of ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider (since grant type is client credentials)

```
public OAuth2AccessToken obtainAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details, AccessTokenRequest request)
        throws UserRedirectRequiredException, AccessDeniedException, 
OAuth2AccessDeniedException {

ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = (ClientCredentialsResourceDetails) details;
return retrieveToken(request, resource, getParametersForTokenRequest(resource), new HttpHeaders());

}
```

We can set the http headers by having new custom Access token provider for client credentials and modifying the method as follows:

```
public OAuth2AccessToken obtainAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details, AccessTokenRequest request)
        throws UserRedirectRequiredException, AccessDeniedException, OAuth2AccessDeniedException {

ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = (ClientCredentialsResourceDetails) details;

    HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();

    headers1.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return retrieveToken(request, resource, getParametersForTokenRequest(resource), headers1);

}
```

You can keep the class same as ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider and add just the header lines.

Last step will be to set this new class as access token in configuration of Oauth2RestTemplate.

```
oauth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new ClientCredentialsCustomAccessTokenProvider());
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Your answer helped me write a similar custom token provider class in the case of ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails (grant_type password) and pass a custom header to retrieve the access token.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation on the answer just to override the default Accept Header interceptor using a Lambda expression:

```
@Bean
protected RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate() {

        @Override
        public <T> RequestCallback acceptHeaderRequestCallback(Class<T> responseType) {
            return request -> {
                request.getHeaders().setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            };
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where this bean should be used? This seems like the cleanest solution to the problem, but I can't figure out how to inject it into the used OAuth2RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring boot mention the authentication scheme as form, it will solve the issue.

```css
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
```