# OAuth2RestTemplate adds charset into content type header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

When trying to get an access token using OAuth2RequestTemplate the call sends the below header in a request

```
"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8”
```

I’d like to drop the charset to not be included there.

I tried to set header value manually through AccessTokenRequest object and a CustomTokenProvider, but it did not work.

Any idea why it is actually including it there and how to get rid of it.

UPDATE : Including the code sample

**OPTION 1 :**

```
String oauthServerUri = "..../access_token";

ClientCredentialsResourceDetails ccDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
ccDetails.setClientId("clientId");
ccDetails.setClientSecret("clientSecret");
ccDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
ccDetails.setAccessTokenUri(oauthServerUri);

AccessTokenRequest tokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();

Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", Arrays.asList("Some Proper Value"));
tokenRequest.setHeaders(headers);
OAuth2ClientContext context = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(tokenRequest);

OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(ccDetails, context);
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
```

**OPTION 2 :**
As an alternative I have tried the approach described here :
[How to set HTTP Header for OAuth2RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999532/how-to-set-http-header-for-oauth2resttemplate/51769621)
Which is implementing `AccessTokenProvider` and setting headers in `obtainAccessToken`. But this did not help either.

Comment: What is the problem with the charset? There should be no reason to remove it. All server should handle it.

Comment: @dur I am working with an API right now that rejects the request when charset is included in a header. I know it is usually not a problem, but in my particular case I need to find a solution.

Comment: I cannot change the server as it's not our code and there's no access to it. So I'll need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the constructor new OAuth2RestTemplate(ccDetails, context); behind it makes a super() which makes a RestTemplate because it extends from it.

```
public OAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext context) {
        super();
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("An OAuth2 resource must be supplied.");
        }

        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorHandler(resource));
    }
```

The RestTemplate constructor puts messageConverters by default.

```
public RestTemplate() {
        this.messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        this.messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
......
```

Maybe a solution could be that once created the object OAuth2RestTemplate you make a restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters) with the MediaType that interests you, from this method (inside RestTemplate class) deletes the previous ones:

```
public void setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        Assert.notEmpty(messageConverters, "At least one HttpMessageConverter required");
        // Take getMessageConverters() List as-is when passed in here
        if (this.messageConverters != messageConverters) {
            this.messageConverters.clear();
            this.messageConverters.addAll(messageConverters);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
[image: Members calling]

If you see the image above, you can see when you do:

```
restTemplate.getAccessToken();
```

call to

```
getRequestCallback(resource, form, headers), extractor, form.toSingleValueMap());

protected RequestCallback getRequestCallback(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) {
    return new OAuth2AuthTokenCallback(form, headers);
}
```

and look what his constructor does:

```
/**
     * Request callback implementation that writes the given object to the request stream.
     */
    private class OAuth2AuthTokenCallback implements RequestCallback {

        private final MultiValueMap<String, String> form;

        private final HttpHeaders headers;

        private OAuth2AuthTokenCallback(MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) {
            this.form = form;
            this.headers = headers;
        }

        public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().putAll(this.headers);
            request.getHeaders().setAccept(
                    Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
            FORM_MESSAGE_CONVERTER.write(this.form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, request);
        }
    }
```

Maybe through inheritance and overwriting methods, you can pass on to that builder the headers that interest you.

Also in OAuth2AccessTokenSupport the method retrieveToken has interesting comments:

```
// Prepare headers and form before going into rest template call in case the URI is affected by the result
authenticationHandler.authenticateTokenRequest(resource, form, headers);
// Opportunity to customize form and headers
tokenRequestEnhancer.enhance(request, resource, form, headers);
```

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see a connection with MediaTypes here. I have actually looked into the option of removing all message converters, but that did not help ... have you tried your suggested approach ? What were in headers ?

Comment: I appreciate the effort to help Francesc. However it is not about adding headers, but to make sure that charset is not in the header. If you want to look into this please try to use the example I have and see what goes out. As dur pointed out the problem is that `FormHttpMessageConverter` sets the charset.

Comment: Here's the reference to the code if you want to see it. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3a0f309e2c9fdbbf7fb2d348be861528177f8555/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.java#L100

Answer (score 0):

You could use a interceptor to wrap your request, see [`ClientHttpRequestInterceptor#intercept`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html#intercept-org.springframework.http.HttpRequest-byte:A-org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution-):

> **intercept**
>
> ```
> ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request,
>                              byte[] body,
>                              ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
>                       throws IOException
> ```
>
> Intercept the given request, and return a response. The given `ClientHttpRequestExecution` allows the interceptor to pass on the request and response to the next entity in the chain.
>
> A typical implementation of this method would follow the following pattern:
>
> 1. Examine the request and body
> 2. Optionally wrap the request to filter HTTP attributes.
> 3. Optionally modify the body of the request.
> 4. Either
>      execute the request using  `ClientHttpRequestExecution.execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest, byte[])`,
>      **or**
>      do not execute the request to block the execution altogether.
> 5. Optionally wrap the response to filter HTTP attributes.

Your modified code:

```java
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(ccDetails, context);
restTemplate.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new new RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor()));
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
```

with

```java
public class RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        HttpRequest requestWrapper = new CustomHttpRequestWrapper(request);
        return execution.execute(requestWrapper, body);
    }
}

public class CustomHttpRequestWrapper extends HttpRequestWrapper {

    public CustomHttpRequestWrapper(HttpRequest request) {
        super(request)
    }        

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        // return all headers, but change the charset
    }
}
```